# Explain doesn't show indexed column as key

Tags: mysql, index, functions

Consider the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
 `game_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `players_no` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `startedon` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `game_type` enum('R','C') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'R',
 `expirydatetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `users_info` text NOT NULL,     
 `lastupdate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `count_temp_user` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `msg_pid` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`),
 KEY `startedon` (`startedon`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11009966 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now,Consider the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE DATE(games.expirydatetime)<CURDATE() AND `players_no` = 2
```

When i Explain the above query i have the following result

`id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref|rows|filtered|Extra
 1 |SIMPLE     |games|ALL |NULL         |NULL|NULL|NULL|314|100.00|Using where`

If i add an index on expirydatetime,i still don't see `expirydate` in key column after explain.Any Explainations for this behavior?Is it because expirydatetime is used within a mysql in-built function?

Will mysql still consider the index on expirydatetime?

Comment: If `EXPLAIN` isn't printing the index name as key it means it isn't using that index. I guess (but I'm not sure) that, as you say, it could be because the column is passed to a function.

Comment: there is a WHERE clause on `expirydatetime`,so its supposed to use the column as index.And also its not suggesting `possible keys`.

Comment: The *WHERE* part is simply stating that the query will filter rows based on a *WHERE* clause (because you have one in your query); *possible_keys* will list the indexes eligible for being used when running your query (it is not a suggestion for you) and *key* will state what index will in fact be used.

Comment: Yes, it's because you are using a function call on the column. Either create a function-based index (if that's possible in MySQL) or don't use the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `possible_keys` shows null because there is no index on any of the two columns used in the `WHERE` clause. So, there is no useful index to even be considered for this query.

But even when you add an index on `(expirydatetime)`, the situation is still not good. Because when you place a column inside a function in a condition, like the `DATE(games.expirydatetime)<CURDATE()`, you are basically forbidding the use of indexes. While it might be possible to use the index on the column, it would still had to do a full index scan (because of the function use) and then access the table for the rows that matched. So the optimizer chooses to do a table scan instead.

---

To make the query use indexes and be more efficient, change the condition to:

```
WHERE expirydatetime < CURDATE() 
  AND players_no = 2
```

and add a composite index on `(players_no, expirydatetime)`

Comment: Does it matter the order for the composite index?

(players_no, expirydatetime) OR (expirydatetime,players_no)?

Comment: @JayKirchoff yes, it does matter.